# Call non static method from different non static class

Tags: c#, exception, windows-8, static, windows-store-apps

I have Mainpage.cs where I have method `public void websocketRequestGetListOfUni()` and then I have this class

```
public class RegisterResponseReceiverRegisterDevice : ResponseReceiver
    {
        public override void onResponseReceived(byte[] header, byte[] response)
        {
            RegisterResponse rr = RegisterResponse.ParseFrom(response);

            var t = new MainPage();
            t.websocketRequestGetListOfUni();
        }
        public override void onError() { }
    }

public void websocketRequestGetListOfUni()
    {
        IntMessage req = IntMessage.CreateBuilder().SetValue(1).Build();
        WebSocketClient.write(3, 7, req, new RegisterResponseReceiverGetListOfUni());
    }
```

I want call method `websocketRequestGetListOfUni()` in class `RegisterResponseReceiverRegisterDevice` but when I call it I get at var `t = new MainPage();`

error

> The application called an interface that was assigned to a different
>   thread.

I also try use

```
this.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => mymethoc);
```

but Dispather is not recognized. Any idea how call my method?

here is Mainpage for better understanding: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz6qb0naa0u0for/Mainpage.cs.txt

Comment: Is there any kind of thread issue. I mean are you doing above task in thread and your mainpage does some UI related tasks?

Comment: Im not fully understand question but class Mainpage is working with UI but these method and class where I need call this method is not doing something with UI only working with data.

Comment: here is Mainpage for better understanding: https://www.dropbox.com/s/oz6qb0naa0u0for/Mainpage.cs.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var t = new MainPage();` is going to instanciate the page (including the UI part (which is instanciated by the Initialise call in MainPage constructor)) so it's a very bad idea to instanciate it just to get access to a method. I strongly sugest that you to reachitecture your code so that you don't need to do that. Particularly you should look at the MVVM patern.

If you still want to do that, you can use the following code to dispatch your method on the UI thread:

```
await CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => mymethoc);
```